# Can I change the Terminal background color in my Mac?

Tags: terminal, mac

I saw a Terminal background color is not background in the network:

[image]

Mine default is black, and its not feels good for me.
So, can I change the Terminal background color in my Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Terminal Menu > Preferences > Profiles

Take your pick - fully customisable...

[image]

Comment: And for a temporarily colored terminal: double click the profile you want to open it